# Capistrano: How to count the number of servers in a role

Tags: cluster-computing, capistrano

I'm creating a deploy.cap which depends on the number of servers there are in the servers.cap to run one task or another, but I can't find/imagine the way to count that array.

This is the servers.cap I have:

```
server "server1.domain.net", :all, :app
server "server2.domain.net", :all, :app
```

Could you give me any good example about how to do that? I'm not a capistrano expert, so please the easier, the better.

Many thanks,
Alfredo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `roles` DSL to get an array of servers that match a given role. Then you can count the number of items in that array.

For example:

```
# Capistrano 3.x
puts roles(:all).size

# Capistrano 2.x
puts roles[:all].servers.size
```

Comment: Tried that and I'm getting the error:
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.9/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `roles': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Do you know what I'm forgetting?

Comment: Got it, it was:
puts roles[:all].servers.size

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize it was for an old version of Capistrano. Glad you figured it out!